# Attempt to dismiss from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an two class, in first class

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {
 SampleViewController2 *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController2 alloc] init];
   [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
```

in second class..

```
- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender {
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

it says warning Attempt to dismiss from view controller.. what is the problem here..

Comment: Why are these actions being triggered from separate classes? You should probably have just one class--a subclass of `UIViewController`--which is responsible for both showing and hiding the `SampleViewController2`.

Comment: Post the actual warning you're getting.

Comment: Attempt to dismiss from view controller < SampleViewController2 : 54325h78> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: Looks like this is since iOS6, i don't think this happened in 5.1 as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
 if (![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed])
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Do a simple google search, the problem that you stated is common...

Answer (score 1):

You might check it before dismissing if your current view's modal view is being dismissed or not

```
if (![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed]){
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```